# data property returns as undefined while it shouldn't. Where am I making a mistake?

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I am currently working on an assignment where we have to make a shopping cart using items from a dropdown list. This list was filled using items from a json file. To make them unique I gave each item some data properties using javascript. This all seems to be working fine untill I actually try to add them to my cart.

For now I tried to just log the item in the console using console log but it keeps returning as undefined. Where am I making a mistake? Here is the code.

```
"use strict";
const btn = document.getElementById('add');
const choiceList= document.getElementById('vegetables');
getVeggies();

async function getVeggies() {
    const response = await fetch("veggies.json")
        if (response.ok) {
            const veggies = await response.json();
            transferVeggies(veggies);
        } else {
            console.log("oops something went wrong!");
        }
};

function transferVeggies(veggies) {
    
    for (const veggie of veggies) {
        addVeggiesToList(veggie);
    }
};

function addVeggiesToList(veggie) {
    let veggieChoice= document.createElement("option");
    veggieChoice.dataset.name = veggie.name;
    veggieChoice.dataset.price = veggie.price;
    veggieChoice.dataset.unit = veggie.unit;
    veggieChoice.innerText = veggie.name + '(' +`${veggie.price}`+"/"+`${veggie.unit}`+')';
    choiceList.appendChild(veggieChoice);

}

btn.onclick = function() {
    addVeggieToBasket(choiceList);
}

function addVeggieToBasket(choiceList) {
   console.log(choiceList.value); //THIS WORKS AND RETURNS THE INNERTEXT DECLARED IN ADDVEGGIESTOLIST
   console.log(choiceList.dataset.name); //THIS JUST RETURNS UNDEFINED
   console.log(choiceList.value.dataset.name); //SAME PROBLEM AS ABOVE, IT RETURNS UNDEFINED

}
```

I should also say that there is no problem declaring the data properties as I can see them appear in the console as they should. I think the problem is that the data properties are declared within a function so they can only be called upon in that same function but it just doesn't make sense to me.

Anyone got an idea how I could make this work?

Comment: The data attributes are on the children inside your `choiceList` element, to get the attributes of all elements loop over `choiceList.children` and get their dataset properties.

Answer (score 0):

use `options` and `selectedIndex` to get the option element.

```js
function addVeggieToBasket(choiceList) {
   console.log(choiceList.value);
   console.log(choiceList.options[choiceList.selectedIndex].dataset.name);

}
```